# Can a square matrix be factored by non square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a square matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Can we always factor $A$ as a product of two non square matrices $B\in M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such $A=BC$. And if its possible and we exclude multiples of $B,C$ is this decomposition unique. Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider $\pmatrix0$ is $\pmatrix{1&0}\pmatrix{0\\1}$ and also $\pmatrix{0&1}\pmatrix{1\\0}$

Comment: If $m > n$, yes.  You can always take block matrices $B = (I \ X)$ and $C = \pmatrix{A\cr 0\cr}$ where $X$ is any $n \times (m-n)$ matrix.

Comment: @RobertIsrael This is a nice decomposition but is this unique ?

Comment: See [rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization). It is possible iff $A$ has rank $m$ or smaller. These decompositions are never unique, but you can produce a canonical rank factorization by modifying the QR factorization.

Comment: @BillIconomou Since $X$ is any $n \times (m-n)$ matrix, of course it's not unique.